# vue js passing "top-level" Boolean not working, only nested

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This is weird. When I define the Boolean property `showModal` at the top level it is simply being ignored by vue.js. Here's what I am doing:

```
//Component:
export default {
  props:['rating', 'showModal'],
  data: function data () {
    return {
      rating: this.rating,
      showModal: this.showModal
    };
  }
};
```

Invoking the view:

```
const sharedRating = {
  title: '',
  remark: ''
};

let showModal = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#rating-edit-container',
  data: {
    showModal: showModal,
    rating: sharedRating
  }
});

showModal = true;
```

Then both values are being passed to the component:

```
  <rating-edit
    :rating="rating"
    :show-modal="showModal"></rating-edit>
```

But when I change the value of `showModal` nothing happens.

If I pass `showModal` inside the rating object and use that nested property everything works fine:

```
const sharedRating = {
  showModal: false,
  title: '',
  remark: ''
};

new Vue({
  el: '#rating-edit-container',
  data: {
    rating: sharedRating
  }
});

sharedRating.showModal = true;
```

Shouldn't "stand alone" boolean properties also be working in Vue or do they always need to be "wrapped"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first of all, I'm not sure what is happening in your component because you are naming a property and a data value with the same name. Without testing, I'm not sure which one wins, but it looks like it is the data property. You should *not* name a property and a data value the same thing. The property will always be available to you.

When you define your data function in a component, it's also important to remember that the data function is only ever called when the component is *created*. Where you set

```
showModal: this.showModal
```

(disregarding for a moment what I said above about this not being a good idea) showModal the *data* property is only ever set *once*. It will never be updated unless you update it inside the component. It will *not* receive changes to the property `showModal`.

If you *wanted* the component to get updates to `showModal` from the outside and for changes to `showModal` in the component be relfected *outside* the component, you need to handle this a little differently.

Vue components are composed in a [props down, events up](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Composing-Components) structure.

```
export default {
  props:['rating', 'showModal'],
  data: function data () {
    return {
      rating: this.rating,
    };
  }, 
  computed:{
    show:{
      get(){ return this.showModal; }
      set(v){ this.$emit('input', v) }
    }
  }
};
```

And then modify the way you use it in your template:

```
rating-edit
  :rating="rating"
  v-model="showModal"></rating-edit>
```

Writing your component in *this* fashion, any update to `showModal` *outside* the component will be reflected *inside* the component as `show`, and any change to `show` *inside* the component will be emitted to the parent. Then because `v-model` listens to `input` events, `showModal` in the parent will be updated with the new value.

Now you may be asking at this point, but why does it work when `showModal` is a property of an object?

When you are passing the object down from the top level into your component, outside your Vue, your root Vue, and your component are all working with the *same* object. Any change to the `showModal` property from any of those places will be reflected in *all* of those places. *If* however, you were to update `showModal` by making a new `sharedRating` object, you would see similar behavior to what you see when you use a boolean. Properties in Vue are *immutable* which means that any change you make to a *primitive* javascript value (string, number, boolean, etc) will not be reflected *outside* the component, and *in fact* Vue will throw a warning about doing that if you are using the development version. Objects and arrays, however, in javascript, are passed by reference. The *reference* is immutable, but the properties of the object and the contents of an array can be changed.

Comment: Wow, that is one awesome great lesson! I really appreaciate your clear and concise explanation. I wish I hadn't been so sloppy when read the vue documentation. You made my day.